# OTP: Start GenEvent under Supervisor With Name

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I'm trying to create a GenEvent process with a specific name (for this question, I'm going with `{:global, :x}`). If I create the GenEvent normally, e.g. `GenEvent.start_link([name: {:global, :x}])`, I can access the GenEvent at that name. That's good. But I also want to create the GenEvent under a supervision tree. To do this, I put the genevent into a Supervision.Spec `worker` spec., and that's when things blow up.

```
iex(1)> {:ok, sup} = Supervisor.start_link([], strategy: :one_for_one)
{:ok, #PID<0.127.0>}
iex(2)> Supervisor.start_child(sup, Supervisor.Spec.worker(GenEvent, [name: {:global, :x}], []))
{:error,
 {{:EXIT,                                                                                                                                                                                    
   {:function_clause,                                                                                                                                                                        
    [{GenEvent, :start_link, [name: {:global, :x}],                                                                                                                                          
      [file: 'lib/gen_event.ex', line: 358]},                                                                                                                                                
     {:supervisor, :do_start_child, 2, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 343]},                                                                                                                 
     {:supervisor, :handle_start_child, 2, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 715]},                                                                                                             
     {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 400]},                                                                                                                    
     {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 629]},                                                                                                                
     {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 661]},
     {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 239]}]}},
  {:child, :undefined, GenEvent, {GenEvent, :start_link, [name: {:global, :x}]},
   :permanent, 5000, :worker, :dynamic}}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer comes from `asonge` in `#elixir` on `irc.freenode.net`. Thanks!)

The `args` value to the `Supervisor.Spec.worker` function takes a list of arguments to pass to the function. For `GenEvent.start_link\1`, it takes a single argument that is a list. As such, I need to pass a list containing one element (the args array to `start_link`) that is the list wanted by `start_link`. As such, the call to `worker` is `Supervisor.Spec.worker(GenEvent, [[name: {:global, :x}]], [])`.